# Проблема с преобразованием кодировки из 'iso8859-1' в 'Windows-1251'

Tags: python, flask

Доброго времени суток как перекодировать на python из 'iso8859-1'  в кодировку 'Windows-1251', если данные приходят как тип bytes.

Пример:

```
Данные отправки: Êëèåíò: 007 (Test test) âåðíóëñÿ.

Отображения в консоли Pycharm: b'\xc3\x8a\xc3\xab\xc3\xa8\xc3\xa5\xc3\xad\xc3\xb2: 007 (Test test) \xc3\xa2\xc3\xa5\xc3\xb0\xc3\xad\xc3\xb3\xc3\xab\xc3\xb1\xc3\xbf.'

В нормальный вид: Клиент: 007 (Test test) вернулся.
```

помогите пожалуйста:

вот пример кода:

```
@app.route('/test', methods=['POST'])
def respond():
    d = request.data
    return Response(d, status=200)
```

Comment: У вас какой-то очень поломанный текст — это символы iso8859-1, закодированные в utf-8. Лучше разберитесь, почему так случилось и как получить данные сразу в нормальной кодировке без всех этих извращений

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну если Вы уже попали в такую ситуацию, то вот можно примерно так:

```
data = b'\xc3\x8a\xc3\xab\xc3\xa8\xc3\xa5\xc3\xad\xc3\xb2: 007 (Test test)' 
print(data.decode().encode('iso8859-1').decode('cp1251'))
```